# Updating text of a pdf, cannot replace string with Arabic word - itext Java

Tags: java, itext, arabic

I am reading a pdf and updating the text of the pdf. It seems to work fine when I replace it with English word but when I replace it with Arabic word, it doesn't work.

In my case, the `PdfObject` would always be of type `Indirect` so `dict.get(PdfName.CONTENTS).isArray()` would be `false` in all cases

```
public static void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);


    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);

        String eredeti = "اختبارات";
        String arabicWord = new String(eredeti.getBytes());

        stream.setData(new String(data).replace("testing", arabicWord ).getBytes("ISO-8859-6"));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();


    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: That kind of replacement code works at best in a very limited manner in some documents. In many documents it doesn't work at all. At worst it actually damages the content.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response @mkl . I would like to your opinion on how to proceed with text replacement. It's working all fine with English, I can't replace Arabic words. Any suggestions please?

Comment: even using ""\u0627\u0644\u0645\" string won't show the data

Comment: *"It's working all fine with English"* - that's merely by luck: for the code to work at all the pdf must be special: all fonts need to have an encoding which is like your jvm's standard encoding and no kerning must be applied. Furthermore, the **Contents** object must be a stream (not an array of streams which also is valid pdf). Simple pdfs usually use the standard 14 fonts (fonts each pdf viewer must bring along) with **WinAnsiEncoding**. Thus, English (and other western European languages) usually in such simple pdfs can be replaced using your code.

Comment: As soon, though, as other languages than western European ones are involved, your code doesn't work at all. As soon as kerning is applied, also not. As soon as other fonts are used and subset embedded, also not. As soon as **Contents** arrays are used, also not. The only somewhat clean way to replace text in pdf page content is to apply redaction-like code to remove the original text and then draw the replacement over it as new text.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the reply. I wrote another implementation that works smoothly. I used `Acrofields` instead of placeholders so I just grab the acrofields, update value of the fields, generate stream and save it into another pdf.

Comment: which pdf library would you suggest me for Java? I am using itext, how is pdfbox? I can get an idea but definitely expert opinion matters a lot

Comment: *"which pdf library would you suggest me for Java"* - it depends on your requirements. E.g. comparing iText and PDFBox, if you want to create new PDFs and expect the library to do layout for you, you'll choose iText; if you want to render PDF pages to bitmap, you'll choose PDFBox; if you cannot pay for a commercial license but want to keep your code closed, you'll choose PDFBox; if you want a support contract, you'll choose iText; etc. pp.

Comment: @mkl I had to update the form fields using Java. I did it via itext as well as via pdfBox. I had faced some issues regarding Arabic fonts to be assigned to acro fields (text fields) in PDFBox but fixed them somehow. I would go for PDFBox because it's free. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451551/unable-ot-save-arabic-words-in-a-pdf-pdfbox-java